# How to check if the user owns the comment on Youtube v3 API commentThreads

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm working on a app that has some youtube features. Using Youtube API calls, I can get [comments](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) and [replies](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) of any video. This is already implemented it's and working just fine.

The problem is, I want to give the logged user the option to edit/delete his comments on the videos (he already can add new comments), but there is no 'authorId' on the API response, only 'authorChannelId', but I don't see how to compare that to the logged user ID.

Right now I can't see how to check if the user owns any comment to actually put the edit/delete button on the UI. What could I do?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/comments#comments-delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I suppose @tehhowch is right. I ended up needing to fetch all the users channels ids (using https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list endpoint), store them somewhere on the app, and them comparing the comment snippet.authorChannelId.value with that array of ids, marking comments as 'owned' or not.

I did that before his comment so I was waiting for some other solution, but seems to be only/right way, so I'm replying my own question.

Thanks tho!